# Save text from webpage to String variable

Tags: android, variables, webview, android-webview

I want to save something from a webpage (loaded into webview) into a Java variable. Is that possible?

Example: I have a webpage with written text: HELLO STACK!. How could I save that text into Java var (String foo = ?????)?

Could I do it with JavaScript/Java cooperation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launch an http request and save the response to text, then process it to get what you want, you wouldnt have to use a webview.

Comment: I've fund this http://bit.ly/bVshR0 (4. page)


public class JSInterface {
//window.jsinterface.specialClick()
     /**
      * This is not called on the UI thread. Post a runnable to invoke
      * loadUrl on the UI thread.
      */
     public void specialClick() {
         handler.post(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 //webview.loadUrl("javascript:alert('Special Click Was Called');");
                 
SAVE something TO STRING HERE!!!!
             }
         });
     }
}

Could that help me anyhow?

Comment: Done it some other way =) Thanks for help!